# Adding CardView & Items to SlidingTabs, Multi-questions

Tags: android, tabs

I'm having a problem with adding CardView to my Tab content, So here's the full story : 
1.Created sliding tabs, with 3 tabs .
2.Made a different layout for each tab ( tab_1, tab_2, tab_3 .
3.Set an adapter ..etc for them, so the tabs are working great ! .

Now, i want to add a different CardView for each tab .
So, i did the following : 
1.Made an item layout, which contain the following ( card view + TextView + Image ) .
2. Made a RecyclerView layout .
3.Made "Person" class, so set the info .
4.Made an adapter for the "item" class .

So, What's the problem ? 
The problem is i can't set the content for the tab, it's showing an empty content, I want to display the items in Tab_1 .

-Forgot to mention, I've made a class for each tab, and it contains the following :

```
public class tab_1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
        return v;

    }

    }
```

The Codes :

Person.java :

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String age;
    int photoId;

    Person(String name, String age, int photoId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.photoId = photoId;
    }
}
```

Adapter.java :

```
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView personName;
        ImageView personPhoto;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        }
    }

    List<Person> persons;

    RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_activity, viewGroup, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
        personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
        personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }
}
```

Tab_1.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_name"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RecyclerView.xml :

---

I've tried to delete item.xml, and put the content in Tab_1.xml, and the tab_1.xml is like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/person_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/person_name"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What i want to : http://i.imgur.com/4iwRaF4.jpg
ofcourse with multi different items, in the Tab 1 layout .

Comment: Why are you using `ListView` with `RecyclerView` Adapter class,

Comment: @ColnsAbt , ops i copied the wrong xml, updated .

Comment: Where is the tap activity its the main thing

Comment: Try to include recycleview.xml insted of item.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue, it was an understanding problem from me about Recycler & Card Views .

Just made the files again and setup everything, now it's working like a charm!.

*Check slidenerd for how to setup if you want a tutorial .

Comment: Can you plz give me that slidened url, i need this too